# Flutter, Having issues parsing a json Model resulting in an empty array

Tags: json, flutter, dart, model, flutter-getx

This is my api calling logic.

using this function in getx Controller. Calling a get API.
I am parsing the "Accommodation" Model in my function and seem to get an empty array. I can assure the api is being called without any network issues

```
accommodationUpdateOrCreationDecision() async {
    List<Accommodation> accommdationModelsList = [];
  
    try {
      var headers = {
        "Authorization":
            "..u3nHlV7nZ5-BlGfoBb91of_RZ4W-Qn_tJOUwremWUA",
      };
      acTitleController.value.text = "hello world";
      var response = await _apiServices.getReq(
        endPoint: '${StringConstants.apiBaseUrl}/host/accommodation',
        headers: headers,
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 400) {
        log("Error Code ==> ${response.statusCode}");
      }
      log("Status Code ==> ${response.statusCode}");
      var accommDataModel = ApiResponseModel.fromJson(
        response.data,
      );
      if (accommDataModel.success == true) {
        accommadateUpdateDeleteBool.value = true;

        for (var data in response.data["data"]["accommodations"]) {
          Accommodation model = Accommodation.fromJson(data);
          accommdationModelsList.add(model);
        }

        log("response Model : ${accommdationModelsList}");
      } else {
        accommadateUpdateDeleteBool.value = false;
      }

      log("response Model success: ${accommDataModel.success.toString()}");
    } catch (e) {
      log("error : ${e.toString()}");
          }
  }
```

This is what my terminal says

```
[log] Status Code ==> 200
[log] response Model : []
[log] response Model success: true
```

There shouldn't be an empty array. Chatgpt cannot fix this.
The problematic part of the code is

```
        for (var data in response.data["data"]["accommodations"]) {
          Accommodation model = Accommodation.fromJson(data);
          accommdationModelsList.add(model);
        }
```

There should have been an array full of this json response

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "message": "Accommodation fetched successfully",
        "baseUrl": "http://64.226.125.111/rev-be/uploads/",
        "accommodations": [
            {
                "location": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        67,
                        24
                    ]
                },
                "status": "Available",
                "_id": "64fc661abdd6042a77392b85",
                "host": "64e762462bbed117abce4cac",
                "title": "Updated Riverside Retreat",
                "desc": "Relax by the river at our tranquil retreat.",
                "images": [
                    "1695389483120-card-img-logo.png"
                ],
                "roomPrice": 2999,
                "dinnerPrice": 699,
                "roomCapacity": 12,
                "dinnerCapacity": 9,
                "services": [],
                "isActive": true,
                "createdAt": "2023-09-09T12:33:30.047Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-09-22T13:31:23.121Z",
                "__v": 0,
                "reviewsId": [
                    "6501bc9189fcd2743e9d0e28",
                    "6501bca689fcd2743e9d0e2f"
                ],
                "rating": 3.7
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the Model im parsing.

```
class Accommodation {
  final String? id;
  final String? host;
  final String? title;
  final String? desc;
  final List<String>? images;
  final int? roomPrice;
  final int? dinnerPrice;
  final Location? location;
  final int? roomCapacity;
  final int? dinnerCapacity;
  final List<dynamic>? services;
  final bool? isActive;
  final DateTime? createdAt;
  final DateTime? updatedAt;
  final int? v;
  final List<dynamic>? bookings;

  Accommodation({
    this.id,
    this.host,
    this.title,
    this.desc,
    this.images,
    this.roomPrice,
    this.dinnerPrice,
    this.location,
    this.roomCapacity,
    this.dinnerCapacity,
    this.services,
    this.isActive,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.v,
    this.bookings,
  });

  factory Accommodation.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Accommodation(
        id: json["_id"],
        host: json["host"],
        title: json["title"],
        desc: json["desc"],
        images: List<String>.from(json["images"].map((x) => "${StringConstants.imageBaseUrl}$x")),
        roomPrice: json["roomPrice"],
        dinnerPrice: json["dinnerPrice"],
        location: Location.fromJson(json["location"]),
        roomCapacity: json["roomCapacity"],
        dinnerCapacity: json["dinnerCapacity"],
        services: List<dynamic>.from(json["services"].map((x) => x)),
        isActive: json["isActive"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["createdAt"]),
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updatedAt"]),
        v: json["__v"],
        bookings: json["bookings"] == null
            ? []
            : List<dynamic>.from(json["bookings"]!.map((x) => x)),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "_id": id,
        "host": host,
        "title": title,
        "desc": desc,
        "images": List<dynamic>.from(images!.map((x) => x)),
        "roomPrice": roomPrice,
        "dinnerPrice": dinnerPrice,
        "location": location!.toJson(),
        "roomCapacity": roomCapacity,
        "dinnerCapacity": dinnerCapacity,
        "services": List<dynamic>.from(services!.map((x) => x)),
        "isActive": isActive,
        "createdAt": createdAt!.toIso8601String(),
        "updatedAt": updatedAt!.toIso8601String(),
        "__v": v,
        "bookings":
            bookings == null ? [] : List<dynamic>.from(bookings!.map((x) => x)),
      };
}

class Location {
  final String? type;
  final List<double>? coordinates;

  Location({
    this.type,
    this.coordinates,
  });

  factory Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Location(
        type: json["type"],
        coordinates:
            List<double>.from(json["coordinates"].map((x) => x?.toDouble())),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "type": type,
        "coordinates": List<dynamic>.from(coordinates!.map((x) => x)),
      };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var responseData = response.data as Map;

for (var data in responseData["data"]["accommodations"]) {
  Accommodation model = Accommodation.fromJson(data);
  accommdationModelsList.add(model);
}
```

Comment: I will try this sooner. This actually seems to be some other issue. Since there are more oher fields than an array and those are successfully fetched, but the array seems to be empty. idk why.